# How to beat grava (ida 5-2 west first)?

Tags: cross-edge

I'm in a bit off a bind here. I've recently picked up Cross Edge again and managed to finally kill the big bird (lindwurm).

But now my nemesis Grava is starting to bug me again. I tried about 10 times, and now I'm going to step over my pride and ask for help :(

So here I am, does anyone know a strategy against this guy?

My current team:

- Raze lvl 141
- York lvl 140
- Aurelia lvl 141
- Misha lvl 130-140 (sometimes switched with Meu lvl 120)

Quick note: my other characters all range from 120 to 125.

Comment: OMG, how do you even reach that level ? I have that game almost abandoned, for the reason those bosses, are extremely hard

Comment: @chuckBirkin by doin the title missions, as i had to do them anyway

Comment: quick note: my levels are nearing 150 now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I beat him.

Who would have guessed that waiting a turn would kill him in one turn? Anyway, case closed.